# Nginx redirect to another domain with diff TLD

Tags: nginx, redirect, server, configuration

So, I have two domains with diff TLDs.
Like example.com and example.org

I want to set Nginx redirect so that I can redirect .com to .org
Like below:

```
example.com => example.org  
www.example.com => www.example.org  
anything.to.any.levels.example.com => anything.to.any.levels.example.org  
example.com/anything/to/any/levels => example.org/anything/to/any/levels  
anything.to.any.levels.example.com/anything/to/any/levels => anything.to.any.levels.example.org/anything/to/any/levels
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression with the `server_name` directive to capture the particular subdomain. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for details.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.*\.)?example\.com$;

    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;

    return 301 $scheme://${subdomain}example.org$request_uri;
}
```